# Cisco 3750 VLANS not connecting to internet

Tags: cisco

Just wondering if you could help figure out what im trying to play with.
So Basically i have a Cisco 3750 Switch which is connected to my modem router.
created 2 vlan(SALES and HR).
HOW CAN I GIVE ACCESS TO INTERNET FOR THIS PC's Connected to these vlans.

here are some config in my switch.
dsl modem router - 192.168.1.1
vlan1 (default) - 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
vlan 10 (SALES) - 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
vlan 20 (HR) - 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0

int fa0/1 - connected to modem router
int range fa0/2-12 - switchport mode access and switchport access vlan 10
int range fa0/13-24 - switchport mode access and switchport access vlan 20

ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1

Am i missing something? hope you can help me out guys, thanks in advance and appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have a default route to your modem/router, but it does not appear you have routing enabled.

Use

> Switch(config)#ip routing

To enable routing. This in turn will allow inter vlan routing and allow data to get out from the other subnets to your DSL Modem/Router.

Make sure your client devices have the correct gateways set for the appropiate subnets.

If your DSL Modem/Router is not performing NAT already, you need to do what SystemCookie has posted and enable NAT on the Cisco switch.

Hope this helps on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: Cisco switches, except for the 6500, cannot NAT. Cisco claims you need special hardware to NAT, and it isn't available on switches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to create NAT-Rules for the VLANS.

So you translate your internal IP to your Public IP.

This is on my Router configured:

```
nat (inside,outside) source static any interface unidirectional
```

Comment: Hi Sir;  im still learning cisco devices, and i have not touched NAT topics yet, was just excited to try vlans and play with it.  based from my reading just awhile ago, NAT is not support in 3750.

Comment: I think their is no need anymore for explaination. Greets :-)